# Is there any way to run the datafactory slice using powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to re run the failed Azure data factory slices by using the powershell cmdlets.

As of now I am re running the slices manually from diagram page. But this is not helping much as I have  more than 500 slices and all are scheduled to run on every week.

Just to brief you : 4 days back my database server  went down, and all the slices are failed to execute and now I want re run all the slice again.

Also I wanted know, is there any way to get failure notification, if slices failed to execute then I should able to get mail or something so that I can get notified.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a complete pain isn't it. I have a powershell script that does this with some nursing. But I just stole it from someone else

Comment: It was from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bigdatasupport/2016/08/31/rerunning-many-slices-and-activities-in-azure-data-factory/ but I'll post it anyway if I can sanitise it

Comment: I found it but I can't really make sense of it haha. Try that link and post back if you have any issuess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also try the script mentioned in the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2015/11/12/azure-data-factory-detecting-and-re-running-failed-adf-slices/) and let us know.
For more information, you may refer the [article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-monitor-manage-pipelines.md) to monitor and manage Azure Data Factory pipelines.

Comment: Thank you this really helped. one quick question do you know how to get number of records inserted by slice using powershell command. So that I can have local audits of data extraction.

Answer (score 0):

Last time a similar issue happened to me I ended up using the "Monitor & Manage" tool from the Azure Portal.
You can use the grid view to select your failed slices, and there is a very useful "Rerun" button [on the top left corner of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D89I.png).

To get email alerts when a slice fails you can add one using the "Metrics and operations" tool.
The settings is quite well hidden [but it exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzSSG.png) :)